# Laravel - Inventory Logic with 2 Eloquent Models

Tags: laravel, logic, inventory-management

I have two eloquent models;

1. InventoryItems
2. Storerooms

By doing belongstoMany relationship between these two models, I can have a logic where there is "one" item in that store room.

How would I make it work if I want to add the same item in the same room? Should there be another pivot column (i.e quantity) in that joint table? or I am approaching this in a wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say go for 3 models instead:

```
Item
- id
- name
- (...)

Room
- id
- name
- (...)

Inventory
- item_id
- room_id
- quantity
- (...)
```

This way the `Inventory` model has relationships with `Item` and `Room`. You're able to add whatever information is required to the `Item` and `Room` models. Additionally the `Inventory` model can have more data as well, for instance where it's stored or how it's stored etc.